# How can I grep for every uneven match?

Tags: regex, grep

Markdowns fenced code blocks look like this

````
```
Here is the code
in many lines
```
````

or like this:

````
```text
Here is the code
in many lines
```
````

The "text" specifies the language which should be used for highlighting.

I want to run over a flat directory and find all files which contain fenced code blocks without a specified language. How can I find fenced code blocks without a specified language?

### What I tried

The following is a superset of what I want:

```
$ grep -rIE -m1 "\`\`\`[[:space:]]*$" *
```

The problem is the closing part. Essentially this finds all files which have a fenced code block at all. But how do I grep for every uneven triple backtick?

My guess is that I have to grep for the complete code block. It is guaranteed that there is either a newline after the triple backticks or a language.

So I tried the following two:

```
grep -rIzPo -m1 "\`\`\`\\n(.*?)\`\`\`" *
grep -rIzEo -m1 "\`\`\`\\n(.*?)\`\`\`" *
```

It found a couple of cases, but it missed at least one. I have no idea why.

### Problem: Two codeblocks

I have many files with multiple code blocks, e.g:

````
```python
a = "Hello"
b = "Stackoverflow"

print(f"{a} {b}")
```

and

```python
    print("foobar")
```
````

Please note that I don't want a file with this content to match! All regexes I tried so far match

````
```

and

```python
    print("foobar")
```
````

Comment: wouldn't `.*?` match across two code blocks? for example a file with two code blocks, both with language specified, will still have two lines that will match ^```$

Comment: The GNU grep solution will look like `grep -rIzPo -m1 '(?m)^```\w+(?:\R(?!```).*)*\R```(*SKIP)(*F)|^```(?:\R(?!```).*)*\R```' *`

Comment: @Sundeep Correct! I will add this example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that'd be easier with [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk).

````
awk 'BEGINFILE{f=0} /^```/{f=!f}
     f&&/^```\s*$/{print FILENAME;nextfile}' *
````

`f` denotes whether last match was even or uneven. It is reset at the beginning of each file, and negated by each match. When `f` is 1 and exit condition (i.e current line is three backquotes followed by zero+ spaces) is met, the program prints filename and moves on to the next file.

Comment: I was building a similar solution.. `awk '/^```[a-zA-Z]/{f=1} /^```\s*$/{if(f) f=0; else {print FILENAME; nextfile}}'`